# jQuery mobile background image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a jQuery mobile site, and I am trying to insert a scalable image into the background, which would adjust to screen size of the phone.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Discover Dubrovnik</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-page {
    background: transparent url(image.gif);
}
</style>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header tex</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" data-theme="d">    
some text
    </div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
<h1>Neki izbornik</h1>
</div>
</div><!-- /page -->
```

When the window is in fullscreen, I get background image, but when I resize it/make it smaller (like the screen in phones), the image isn't resized and it is not centered, so I can only see one part of it...

Connected jQuery and CSS files are downloaded from jquerymobile.com

Answer (score 23):

For jquery mobile and phonegap this is the correct code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(imgage.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
.ui-page {
    background: transparent;
}
.ui-content{
    background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the background never shows up. In Firebug, it seems that the body style is overridden by .ui-overlay-c style from JQM.

Comment: Similarly no joy using this.

Answer (score 20):

None of the above worked for me using JQM 1.2.0

This did work for me:

```
.ui-page.ui-body-c {
    background: url(bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;  
}
```

Comment: Good stuff. In addition to this add 
.ui-body-c, .ui-overlay-c { background: none;} to cancel out the jQuery mobile background that overlays the image

Comment: This one work for me but the background image also shown in the left menu. I believed it's  swatch B. Is there anyway to disable the left swatch B or have it own backgroud. JQM1.2.1

Answer (score 10):

I think your answer will be `background-size:cover`.

```
.ui-page
{
background: #000;
background-image:url(image.gif);
background-size:cover;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I scale <img> tags. If you want to make it a background image you can set it's position to absolute, place the image where you want (using the: top, bottom, left, right declarations), and set it's z-index below the rest of your page.

```
//simple example
.your_class_name {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```
//background image example
.your_background_class_name {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

To implement this you would simply place an image tag inside the data-role="page" element of your page(s) that has the ".your_background_class_name" class and the src attribute set to the image you want to have as your background.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great solution Jasper, I also needed to make the following elements backgrounds transparent -- .ui-page,.ui-content{
 background: transparent;
}

Answer (score 6):

Try this. This should work:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" style="background-image: url('#URL'); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"
    data-theme="a">
```

Answer (score 1):

just simple replace your class with this.

```
.ui-page
{
   background: transparent url(images/EarthIcon.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

I have same issue and i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add !important tag to all css elements in Paolo's answer! Works fine for me JQM+phonegap

EXAMPLE:

```
body {
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQM 1.4.2 this one works for me (Change theme to the used one):

```
.ui-page-theme-b, .ui-page-theme-b .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background: transparent url(../img/xxx) !important;
    background-repeat:repeat !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer works for me

```
<style type="text/css">
#background{ 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100% !important; 
height: 100% !important; 
background: url(mobile-images/limo-service.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 
z-index: -1; 
} 
.ui-page{ 
background:none; 
}
</style>
```

also add `id="background"` to the div for your content section

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override ui-page class in your css:

```
.ui-page {
    background: url("image.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my experience:

in some situations the background image url have to be put separately for all page parts -
I use:

```
var bgImageUrl = "url(../thirdparty/icons/android-circuit.jpg)";

...

$('#indexa').live('pageinit', function() {

   $("#indexa").css("background-image",bgImageUrl);
   $("#contenta").css("background-image",bgImageUrl);
   $("#footera").css("background-image",bgImageUrl);
   ...
}
```

where "indexa" is the id of the whole page, and the "contenta" and "footera" are id-s of the 
content and footer respectively.

This works for sure in PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile