# JQuery Mobile setting image background with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to set an image (bg.jpg) as a background image but I'm not doing well. Here's the css code:

```
.ui-page{
  background: #000000 url('img/background.jpg') repeat;
}
```

The page still looks the same if i change images or colors background...

Thanks!

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467806/jquery-mobile-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.ui-page
{
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(img/background.jpg);/* Check bg.jpg || backgroung.jpg */
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Can be possible duplicate of [jquery mobile background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467806/jquery-mobile-background-image)

Comment: Use `!important` in the above `css properties` and then check.