# JQM: Need to set scalable background image for each content page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

This looks like a simple job but had me going nuts from few days. I have a multi-page JQM application and I need to set a different scalable background image to each page.

I followed all the methods explained in the link [jquery mobile background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467806/jquery-mobile-background-image).

It seems that nothing works on the latest version of JQM (1.3.0). When I debug in Chrome there always seems to be an overlay hiding the background image. Also none of the methods target the content div for multi page environment. Even if I get the style on ui_page class working, I am worried that I will not be able to use different image on different page.

Is there a simple method to statically assign a different background image (that scales) on every page of the multi-page app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CQRRC/

**CSS used:**

```
.ui-page {
    background:url(http://decentpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/05-Cute-Puppy-Wallpapers.jpg) !important;
    background-size:cover  !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat  !important;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Solution with different pictures on different pages: http://jsfiddle.net/CQRRC/1/

Comment: Thanks, but how do I put different image on each page? I read my question again and I realize I have to be more clear :(

Comment: Awesome !! Let me try this out on my project. I always ignore the !important based solutions, as while learning Jquery I read this being as a bad practice. However considering the simplicity of the solution I am going to change my mind forever :)

Comment: !important must be used here because we are changing existing solution. Other solution would be to remove problematic lines from  framework itself.