# Jquery Mobile - Make Background Image responsive

Tags: jquery-mobile, background-image

I have used `Jquery Mobile`. I have added background image like this`<body background ="6.jpg">`.

I want to make background image responsive. What process should i follow to make it responsive? Please Suggest.

**Update**

I have tried using this

```
body {
    background: url(6.jpg) ;
   background-size:cover; 



}
.ui-page {
    background: transparent;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ui-content{
    background: transparent;
}
```

followed this link [Stacjoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467806/jquery-mobile-background-image)

but failed.  Width of the image is responsive but height is getting too smaller than the original image.

Answer (score 3):

You can working for example with this: http://jquerypicture.com/

The important think is (generell for responsive) you must working with media queries.

PS: Instead of seeting the background in the body tag, please use a class for this.

Comment: can i do this using `jquery mobile` ? I dont want to use any other plugins thats why asking?

Comment: yes, the important is are the media queries. another good site for your problem: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/api/mediahelpers.html